# Dynamic values to HttpParams

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I have a comma separated string of column and value pair which needs to be passed as parameters to HttpParams. For example the values will be like below. Please advise if this is the right way or need some modification

```
 let tmpValues = "Col1=Val1,Col2=Val2"
   let  SplitVals = tmpValues.split(",")
   let params = new HttpParams();
   foreach(var val in SplitVals )
   { var colVl = val.split("=")
      params.append(colVl[0], colVl[1]);  
   }
```

Comment: I think you need to assign the value back to `params` after append: `params = params.append(colVl[0], colVl[1]);`. Otherwise the `params` variable will not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Angular docs [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#append) `append()` returns a new `HttpParams` instance with the appended value rather than updating the existing instance. Change your loop to this:

```js
foreach (var val in SplitVals)
{
    var colVl = val.split("=");
    params = params.append(colVl[0], colVl[1]);
}
```

Or perhaps a `reduce` over the split would be a better fit for the JS paradigm:

```js
let params = tmpValues.split(',').reduce((accum, val) => {
    let pair = val.split('=');
    return accum.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
}, new HttpParams());
```

`reduce` iterates through the array and passes the initial value (the second parameter to `reduce`) and the current item to the inner function. The return value from each call is passed as the accumulator (`accum` parameter) for the next call, until the final return value is returned as the result.

Comment: Typo error for `.Split` and `.Append`, should be in lowercase.

Comment: @YongShun Thanks Yong. I'm a C# programmer with ingrained habits :P

Comment: Corey, thanks for your response. It worked and I did learn something new on how to reduce iteration.